# How to get prediction p-values of an XGBClassifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I'd like to know how confident an XGBClassifier is for each prediction it makes. Is it possible to have such a value? Or is the predict_proba already indirectly the confidence of the model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your intuition is indeed correct: `predict_proba` returns the probability of each example being of a given class; from the [docs](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBClassifier.predict_proba):

> `predict_proba`(*data, output_margin=False, ntree_limit=0*)
>
> Predict the probability of each *data* example being of a given class.

This probability in turn is routinely interpreted **in practice** as the *confidence* of the prediction.

That said, this is an ad-hoc, practical interpretation, and it has nothing to do with p-values or any other measure of statistical rigour; generally speaking and AFAIK, there are no such measures available for this (and similar) machine learning techniques.

On a more general level, you may be interested to know that p-values themselves have been quickly falling out of grace among statisticians; some quick links:

- [The ASA's Statement on p-Values: Context, Process, and Purpose](https://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00031305.2016.1154108#.WtCvRX9LfmE) (American Statistician)
- [Statisticians issue warning over misuse of *P* values](https://www.nature.com/news/statisticians-issue-warning-over-misuse-of-p-values-1.19503) (Nature)
- [The problems with p-values are not just with p-values](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/research/published/asa_pvalues.pdf) (Andrew Gelman @ American Statistician)
- [The problem with p-values](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-case-study-of-the-p-value-f0d708861334) (Towards Data Science blog post)