# How to get significance test (e.g. p-value) using python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics

So I built a custom classifier for an NLP Task using gensim. Now I have two simple Arrays, the test-set (majorityVoteArray) and the predictions of my classifier (similarityArray).

I can get the get the confusion matrix and a report on accuracy fairly easy using sklearn:

```
confusion_matrix(majorityVoteArray, similarityArray)

classification_report(majorityVoteArray, similarityArray))
```

However, neither of these contains any information on the significance of my results. However, since it is a classification task over large pieces of text my test set is somewhat small, so I am rather skeptical. Is there an as easy way to get the significance test for as the above functions?

If it helps, I have the results for my interrater-agreement score for building the test-set:

```
kappa 0.7987223933637878
fleiss 0.7981046559538525
alpha 0.7992465904091509
scotts 0.7978992520897492
```

Comment: You don't seem to have a firm grasping of what a statistical significance test actually *means*; do you really have alternate hypotheses to compare? I suggest googling on "hypothesis testing"; also, my answer here might be helpful: [How to get prediction p-values of an XGBClassifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49812343/how-to-get-prediction-p-values-of-an-xgbclassifier/49817830#49817830)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. You are my grasp is certainly not as firm as I like and I want to learn. So here is what I was trying to do: I am worried that I have to little labelled data and that the accuracy of my classifier could be missleading. In order to explore this issue I wanted to do a p-value to see the likelihood that the predictions made by my classifier are actually just a permutation of randomly guessing predicitions (the null-hypothesis). I have had a look at the links you supplied, but I am not sure how they apply.

Comment: These details should be part of your question, so please edit it & add them; as for the links in the linked answer, their general idea is to show that null hypothesis significance testing (NHST) and p-values have been falling out of grace in statistics

Comment: It seems that what you are looking for is Cross Validation and not a statistical hypothesis testing. Cross Validation will check the ability of your model to generalize (and by that check that you're not witnessing a statistical fluke).
Hypothesis testing is often used to validate the statistical significance of features in your model, but that theory is only analytically well-defined for linear regression.

Comment: Thanks Shahar but cross validation is actually not possible, since I use unsupervised training from a huge data set, which is unfortunately unlaballed and I lack access to resources to make it happen.